# Topology of the Poincaré group $\mathcal{P}(1,3)$

Tags: special-relativity, mathematical-physics, group-theory, topology, poincare-symmetry

This is planned as a Q&A session, hopefully it serves people who seek a mathematical foundation to (relatively) known results in standard textbooks on QM or QFT.

**Question:** What is the topology of the full Poincaré group in 1+3 spacetime dimensions? What about the restricted Poincaré group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a generic 4-vector $x^\mu$ in the (1+3) Minkowski spacetime of metric tensor $\eta = \text{diag} (+---)$, a Poincaré transformation $P_4$ acts on $x^\mu$ as
$$x'^\mu = P_4 x^\mu = \Lambda^{\mu}_{~\nu} x^{\nu} + a^\mu$$

Here [The Topology of the Lorentz group in 1+3 dimensions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/364965/the-topology-of-the-lorentz-group-in-13-dimensionsit) it is proven that the set of Lorentz transformations $\{\Lambda\}$, by mapping it into $\mathbb R^{16}$ as a vector space and topologizing it with the supremum norm, becomes a topological Lie group. The polar decomposition theorem for the Lorentz group (a glimpse on it one can find here: https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0211047) creates the **topological** decomposition (*i.e.* as a manifold, *not* as a group direct product, which it isn't):

$$(\mathcal L) = \text O (1,3) = \text O (3) \times \mathbb R^3 $$

This gives us a hint on how to look for the topology of the full Poincaré group. First ensure it is a topological group by a proper embedding(*) into $\text{GL}(n,\mathbb R)$. This is done by creating the generic **5x5** matrix

$$ P_5 = \left(\begin{array} \ \Lambda_{4\times 4} \ a_{4\times 1} \\ \bf{0} _{1\times 4} \ 1 \end{array}\right)\in \text{GL}(5,\mathbb R), \Lambda\in\text O(1,3), a\in\text T_4$$
which acts on a generic **5x1** matrix $ A = \left(\begin{array} \ x^\mu \\ 1 \end{array}\right)$.

Endowing this set of matrices with the same supremum norm, it becomes a topological space. One can show that the set of all $P_5$'s becomes a group under matrix multiplication (prove it!) and under the norm it becomes a topological group (the norm ensures the continuity of group operations). A Lie group actually, as it a closed subgroup of $\text{GL}(5,\mathbb R)$. Then we can easily establish the group isomorphism between the set of all Poincaré transformations $P_4$ and the set of all $P_5$ (prove it!).

Therefore, the topology of the Poincaré group in 1+3 dimensions is the topology of the group of matrices $P_5$. This group is immediately seen to be connected, locally connected and non-compact (hence by Schreier's theorem, it admits a simply connected non-compact universal covering group). Moreover, we have the matrix decomposition:

$$ P_5 = \left(\begin{array} \ 1 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ a^0 \\ 0 \ 1 \ 0 \ 0 \ a^1 \\ 0 \ 0 \ 1 \ 0 \ a^2 \\ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 1 \ a^3 \\ 0 \ 0\ 0 \ 0 \ 1 \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array} \ \Lambda_{4\times 4} \ 0_{1\times 4} \\ 0_{4\times 1} \ 1 \end{array}\right) $$

which entails the topological decomposition (homeomorphism):

$$ P_5 = \mathcal P (1,3) = \mathbb R^4 \times \text O (1,3) = \mathbb R^4 \times \text O (3) \times \mathbb R^3. $$

The latter is the topological structure of the set of all Poincaré transformations. Specializing on restricted Lorentz transformations, we have

$$ \left(P_5\right)_{+}^{\uparrow} = \mathcal P_{+}^{\uparrow} (1,3) = \mathbb R^4 \times \text{SO} (3) \times \mathbb R^3. $$

By this topological decomposition we obtain that the restricted Poincaré group is double-connected (its fundamental group has two elements, $\pm \bf{I}_{2\times 2}$), hence its universal covering group $\widetilde{\mathcal{P}_{+}^{\uparrow}} $ is a double cover.

(*) In the comments below, Rod questions if the word "embedding" is properly used (from a diff. geom. point of view) or perhaps "immersion" would have been the right word. Here we are dealing with matrix groups which are very particular Lie groups, i.e. analytic submanifolds of $\mathbb R^n$ for various values of "n". The finesse which distinguishes an immersion (a local mapping) from embedding (global mapping) doesn't exist, because any two topologies on $\mathbb R^n$ are equivalent.

Comment: I haven't had time to read this in detail (I'm not the fastest understander in the West by any means), but some comments are in order: firstly (somewhat pedantically) all Lie groups are topological groups, so "topological Lie group" is a tautology. Do you mean to say that the embedding process bestows a new topology (*i.e.* that inherited as relative to the topology of $\mathbb{R}^{16}$) on it that is not the Lie group topology? But this would seem to tell against the word "embedding"; I haven't read the paper in detail, but if it is indeed an embedding as opposed to an immersion, then ....

Comment: the Lie group is closed in the superset's topology and the Lie group and relative topologies are the same. Secondly, I've added quite a few words to clear up a mistake I made on reading this the first time: please check that the sense is what you mean. Great idea BTW: I like this kind of Q&A for people to share their efforts to understand a topic; it's a bit like Fermi's famous group paper reading sessions, which my own PhD supervisor emulated.

Comment: The supremum norm is equivalent to other norms one can place on $\text{Mat}_{n\times n} (\mathbb R)$, so the topology of the submanifold can be safely taken to be the subspace (inherited) one. We don't have Klein bottles or Moebius strips here, so everything seems straightforward.

Comment: What I am getting at: is the inherited topology is the same as the Lie group topology, *i.e.* that generated by a base of sets of the form $\exp(\mathbf{h})$ where $\mathbf{h}\subseteq \mathfrak{p}(1,\,3)$ is a neighborhood in the Lie algebra? This happens whenever the Lie group is closed in $\text{Mat}_{n\times n} (\mathbb R)$. It doesn't happen, for example, for an [irrational slope subgroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1210717/an-irrational-flow-on-a-torus-is-dense) of the Abelian torus group. This is the kind of thing I mean - one has to be careful with inherited topologies.

Comment: Yes, it is. A basis of neighborhoods of every point in the group's manifold is given by set of open balls in the supremum norm topology or equivalently in the set of open neighborhoods mapped from the Lie algebra to the Lie group by the exponential. I will try to find an exact proof, however.

Comment: The proof is well known, as long as one can prove the Lie group is closed in the superset's topology. Now I guess that's fairly clear thinking about this some more; it would take a little time to put my hand on / come up with a proof.

Comment: OK, if you find it and share it with me, I can amend the answer. Rod, can you take a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2494315/universal-covering-group-of-a-semidirect-product-of-lie-groups? It's the connection between universal covering groups and semidirect products of Lie groups.